# Javascript removeEventListner inside the callback?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

How to addEventListener which will be triggered only one time + passing arguments to it?

```
function () {
    var params = ...

    elem.addEventListener('load', function(event, params) {
        elem.removeEventListner('load', ...);
        do_something(params)
    }
}
```

Comment: set a variable to true, then once it's run set it to false. Make an if statement and put all of your code inside the if. The if checks that the variable is true. If it's false, it does nothing. Then, at the end of the if for true set a timeout for something that's like 100 milliseconds and then run removeEventListener and set the variable to false

Comment: This way the variable will prevent it from running twice, and then after the function is done it will remove the listener

Comment: The code in which this needs to be done is complex, dirty solutions are not possible here.

Comment: Save the callback as a variable so you can reference it by name to removeEventListener() it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using addEventListener, you can provide a config object as a second argument, where you can specify that it should run once (like the code below). Regarding passing an extra argument to your event callback, you can use the method bind by providing the context and the extra argument

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#btn');


button.addEventListener('click', function (params, ev) {
  
  console.log(params);
  
}.bind(button, { name: 'test'}), {
  once: true
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
 <button id="btn">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my 17 years of development, I never knew that was an option that existed. +1 for teaching me something new and useful!

Answer (score 1):

If you name your anonymous function you can reference it inside:

```
function () {
    var params = ...

    elem.addEventListener('load', function callback(event, params) {
        elem.removeEventListner('load', callback);
        do_something(params)
    }
}
```

It wont leak to the global scope so you can name all of your 'one-time' events `callback`.

Answer (score 1):

The `removeEventListener` method requires you to specify which function you're removing. That means you need a reference to that function so you can pass it to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. Something like this:

```
function bindListener(elem, params) {
    var listener = function() {
        do_something(params);
        elem.removeEventListener('load', listener);
    }
    elem.addEventListener('load',listener);
}
```